# Guess the Object - I am usually partially encased in a sheath, of plastic or metal

Tags: riddle

> I have been around since even before Cuneiform writing.
>
> I am usually partially encased in a sheath, of plastic or metal.
>
> I support you on your journeys, long and short.
>
> I come in all different colors, varieties, and sizes.
>
> I am pretty useless without my counterparts and nobody wants me alone.
>
> I am also an important part of a common childhood lesson.

**What object am I?**

Comment: I was going to say belt, but that's a different kind of common childhood lesson.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are:

> Shoelaces

I have been around since even before Cuneiform writing.

> Both invented roughly 6000 years ago

I am usually partially encased in a sheath, of plastic or metal.

> Aglet!

I support you on your journeys, long and short.

> Support your feet

I come in all different colors, varieties, and sizes.

> True

I am pretty useless without my counterparts and nobody wants me alone.

> Need the other lace and shoes to be useful

I am also an important part of a common childhood lesson.

> Tying your shoes  (This was the clue that led my brain to this answer)

Comment: Congratulations! This is the correct answer! :) @puzzle-guesser

Answer (score 8):

I would guess that you are...

> Ink

I have been around since even before Cuneiform writing.

> The materials needed to create ink have been in the Earth since before Cuneiform writing.

I am usually partially encased in a sheath, of plastic or metal.

> Usually the ink will be placed in plastic or metal to be used as a pen.

I support you on your journeys, long and short.

> Pens can come in handy for long writing tasks such as essays, but are also quite useful for short tasks, like signing your name.

I come in all different colors, varieties, and sizes.

> There are many different colors, varieties, and sizes of ink (when used in pens).

I am pretty useless without my counterparts and nobody wants me alone.

> The ink in a pen is useless without something to write on. A pen is usually used with paper, which is a valuable and almost necessary counterpart.

I am also an important part of a common childhood lesson.

> Children may choose to use pens to write their notes or do their homework while taking lessons.

Comment: Really good guess, but incorrect!